# How to run the subquery first in presto

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto, in-clause

I have the following query:

```
select * 
from Table1 
where NUMid in (select NUMid 
                from Table2 
                where email = 'xyz@gmail.com')
```

My intention is to get the list of all the NUMids from table2 having an email value equal to xyz@gmail.com and use those list of NUMids to query from Table1.

In presto, the query is running the outer query first. Is there a way to run and store the result of inner query and then use it in the outer query in presto?

Comment: On most versions of SQL, you would index `Table2` so that the above subquery lookup is very fast.  But, Presto doesn't support regular indices, so I don't know what can be done here.

Comment: Strange, since the inner query would greatly simplify the outer query! Are you concerned because it is taking a long time? I wonder if it would run more efficiently if done via `JOIN`?

Answer (score 0):

The optimizer can do what it likes.  In this case, it should be running the inner query once and then essentially doing a `JOIN` (technically a "semi-join") operation.

In many databases, `exists` with appropriate indexes solves the performance problem.

If you want to ensure that the subquery is evaluated only once, you can move it to the `ON` clause.  The correct equivalent query looks like:

```
select t1.* 
from Table1 t1 join
     (select distinct t2.NUMid 
      from Table2 t2
      where t2.email = 'xyz@gmail.com'
     ) t2
     on t1.NUMid = t2.NUMid;
```

The `select distinct` is important for the `join` code to be equivalent to the `in` code.  However, if you know there are no duplicates, this is more colloquially written without a subquery:

```
select t1.* 
from Table1 t1 join
     Table2 t2
     on t1.NUMid = t2.NUMid
where t2.email = 'xyz@gmail.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

Presto and [Trino](https://trino.io) ([formerly known as PrestoSQL](https://trino.io/blog/2020/12/27/announcing-trino.html)) execute that query as a "semi join" operation: it builds an in-memory index with the rows coming from the inner query and probes the rows of the outer query against that index. If value is present, the row from the outer query is emitted, otherwise, it's filtered out.

In recent versions of Trino, there's a feature called "dynamic filtering", which allows the query engine to dynamically filter and prune data for the outer query at the source based on information obtained dynamically from the inner query. You can read more about it in these blog posts:

- [Dynamic filtering for highly-selective join optimization](https://trino.io/blog/2019/06/30/dynamic-filtering.html)
- [Dynamic partition pruning](https://trino.io/blog/2020/06/14/dynamic-partition-pruning.html)